# What does a function of $C^{1+\epsilon}$ mean?

Tags: analysis

I am starting to read *Boundary Behavior of Holomorphic Funtions of Several Complex Varieties* by E.M. Stein. I don't know the meaning of the following symbol:

> The class $C^{1+\epsilon}$ would suffice...

Can you tell what does $C^{1+\epsilon}$ mean? This symbol appears in the first page and there is no definition of such symbol in this book. And $C^{2-\epsilon}$ appears when introducting the Green's function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing the context, I'd say, $C^1$ functions, whose derivative is $\epsilon$-Hölder continuous.

Comment: @martini Thank you. This symbol appears in the first page and there is no  definition of such symbol in this book. And $C^{2-\epsilon}$ appears when introducting the Green's function. Holder continous should be $C^{1,\epsilon}$, I think

Comment: There is also no definition, of say $C^2$. Some authors use $C^{1+\epsilon}$ instead of $C^{1,\epsilon}$, and $C^{2-\epsilon}$ is just $C^{1,1-\epsilon}$ in that sense.

Comment: While there are other definitions of fractional derivatives, it's hard to think of one that works well enough with "continutity" to be so introduced without a careful definition.

Comment: From the context (the author starts to recall "known" results from potential theory), it is very unlikely, that something besides Hölder continuity is meant, I'd say.

Comment: @martini Thank you. It is Holder continuous after I read over a 1960s book.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for commenting. This symbol turns out to be an "old-fashioned" usage of Holder continity

Comment: @Jason785: May I suggest inviting martini to post an Answer?

Comment: @hardmath I don't know how to invite martini to post an answer. Math StackExchange is totally new to me. Perhaps I think a comment is enought to inform freshmen like me to understand such symbols. Afterall this is not a key problem.

Answer (score 1):

$C^{1+\epsilon}$ means $C^1$ functions, whose derivative is $\epsilon$-Hölder continuous.

*(quoting martini's comment so that the question doesn't appear unanswered)*